# enable web analytics customized reports

Tags: 2010, powershell, web-analytics

I'm running SharePoint Server Standard 2010. I don't see a "Customize Report" button in the Analyze tab of the Site Collection Web Analytics report. When I go to PowerShell and run

```
Get-SPFeature -Site http://servername/sites/thesite
```

WACustomReports is not returned in the site feature list. Then, when I run

```
Enable-SPFeature WACustomReports –URL http://servername/sites/thesite
```

I get an error message that says: "The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site defined by the URL http://servername/sites/thesite." I did a web search based on that error message, but didn't find anything useful.

How can I enable customized error reports?

Comment: Do you see WACustomReports directory under FEATURES folder?

Comment: @AshishPatel Yes, it is there.